# Disable badge for specific app with a script

Tags: applescript, notifications, script

I know that I can turn on/off the badge from the notifcation center, but is there a way to do it with a script?

If possible I would love to do for a specific app, otherwise it will be fun to turn it off for all the apps.

So far I was able to do this:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
activate
set the current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.notifications"
tell application "System Events"
   tell process "System Preferences"
        select row 2 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of window "Notifications" 
        click checkbox "Badge app icon"  of group 1 of window "Notifications" 
   end tell
end tell
```

end tell

*It has only one problem*:

- the list must stay the same and you have to know the Index. Is there a way to access by name?

PS: i've used the very handy http://pfiddlesoft.com/uibrowser/index-downloads.html for finding out how to identify objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* works for me under **macOS High Sierra**:

Note: Change `"Calendar"` in `set appName to "Calendar"` to the appropriate target app.

---

```
set appName to "Calendar"

if running of application "System Preferences" then
    quit application "System Preferences"
    delay 1
end if
tell application "System Preferences"
    set the current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.notifications"
    delay 1
    tell application "System Events"
        tell table 1 of scroll area 1 of window 1 of application process "System Preferences"
            repeat with i from 2 to (count rows)
                if value of static text 1 of group 1 of UI element 1 of row i is appName then
                    select row i
                    exit repeat
                end if
            end repeat
        end tell
        delay 0.2
        click checkbox "Badge app icon" of group 1 of window 1 of application process "System Preferences"
    end tell
    quit
end tell
```

---

**System Preferences** does not need to be visible for this to work and why there is no `activate` *command* in the *example* **AppleScript** *code*. Additionally if **System Preferences** is already open, it is first closed before the rest of the *code* is processed. This is done for a couple of reasons, the first of which was already stated and secondly seeing the UI Events processed is a visual distraction and can be annoying.

Also note that the *value* of the `delay` *commands* may need to be adjusted for your system, and or additional `delay` *commands* may or may not be needed. Adjust *values* of and or add/remove the `delay` *commands* as appropriate.

---

For a version that acts on multiple applications and or all applications in **Notification Center** in **System Preferences**, see my answer to: [Remove multiple app badge icons with one script?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/317545/remove-multiple-app-badge-icons-with-one-script/317570#317570)

---

**Note:** The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not employ any *error handling* and is meant only to show one of many ways accomplish a task. The onus is always upon the User to add/use appropriate *error handling* as needed/wanted.

Comment: thanks, works like a charm. Out of curisoity, how/where did you learn all the commands and language to program this? I google for hours but it's hard to find example or references to how to interact with the UI and so on.