# Remove multiple app badge icons with one script?

Tags: applications, applescript, notifications

I found this link to remove a badge icon from a single app.

[Disable badge for specific app with a script](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/316948/disable-badge-for-specific-app-with-a-script)

Is it possible to create a script with multiple apps to remove all badges at once?

Running High Sierra 10.13.3

Comment: Is it possible?  Yes.  What *specifically* would you like to do?  What have you tried?

Comment: Id like to run a script to remove badge app icons from all message and email applications. Currently I have four separate scripts that take care of apps individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* was tested under **macOS High Sierra**.

The following is modified *code* from my answer you linked in your OP:

This version acts on *applications* in **Notification Center** in **System Preferences** that are defined in the `appNameList` *list*.

Change the application names and or add or remove them in the `appNameList` *list* as needed:

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
set appNameList to {"Calendar", "Games", "Mail", "Messages"}

if running of application "System Preferences" then
    quit application "System Preferences"
    delay 1
end if
tell application "System Preferences"
    set the current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.notifications"
    delay 1
    tell application "System Events"
        tell table 1 of scroll area 1 of window 1 of application process "System Preferences"
            repeat with i from 2 to (count rows)
                select row i
                delay 0.25 --   # Do not set any lower, increase if necessary!
                set theValue to (value of static text 1 of group 1 of UI element 1 of row i)
                repeat with thisApp in appNameList
                    if theValue contains thisApp then
                        --  # Use 0 with clickCheckBox() to check the check box.
                        --  # Use 1 with clickCheckBox() to uncheck the check box.
                        my clickCheckBox(1)
                    end if
                end repeat
            end repeat
        end tell
    end tell
    quit
end tell

on clickCheckBox(i as integer)
    tell application "System Events"
        tell group 1 of window 1 of application process "System Preferences"
            --  # if the value of checkbox is 0, it's unchecked.
            --  # if the value of checkbox is 1, it's checked.  
            if value of checkbox "Badge app icon" is equal to i then
                click checkbox "Badge app icon"
            end if
        end tell
    end tell
end clickCheckBox
```

---

**System Preferences** does not need to be visible for this to work and why there is no `activate` *command* in the *example* **AppleScript** *code*. Additionally if **System Preferences** is already open, it is first closed before the rest of the *code* is processed. This is done for a couple of reasons, the first of which was already stated and secondly seeing the UI Events processed is a visual distraction and can be annoying.

Also note that the *value* of the `delay` *commands* may need to be adjusted for your system, and or additional `delay` *commands* may or may not be needed. Adjust *values* of and or add/remove the `delay` *commands* as appropriate.

---

This version acts on all *applications* in **Notification Center** in **System Preferences**.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
if running of application "System Preferences" then
    quit application "System Preferences"
    delay 1
end if
tell application "System Preferences"
    set the current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.notifications"
    delay 1
    tell application "System Events"
        tell table 1 of scroll area 1 of window 1 of application process "System Preferences"
            repeat with i from 2 to (count rows)
                select row i
                delay 0.25 --   # Do not set any lower, increase if necessary!

                --  # Use 0 with clickCheckBox() to check the check box.
                --  # Use 1 with clickCheckBox() to uncheck the check box.

                my clickCheckBox(1)

            end repeat
        end tell
    end tell
    quit
end tell

on clickCheckBox(i as integer)
    tell application "System Events"
        tell group 1 of window 1 of application process "System Preferences"
            --  # if the value of checkbox is 0, it's unchecked.
            --  # if the value of checkbox is 1, it's checked.  
            if value of checkbox "Badge app icon" is equal to i then
                click checkbox "Badge app icon"
            end if
        end tell
    end tell
end clickCheckBox
```

---

For a version that acts on just one specific application in **Notification Center** in **System Preferences**, see my answer to: [Disable badge for specific app with a script](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/316948/disable-badge-for-specific-app-with-a-script/316959#316959)

---

**Note:** The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not employ any other *error handling* then what's shown and is meant only to show one of many ways accomplish a task. The onus is always upon the User to add/use appropriate *error handling* as needed/wanted.

Comment: Awesome! To my understanding this will remove badge app icons from every app. Are there any variables I can enter to remove only 4 or 5 apps? If not this will do just fine!

Comment: @yowats0n, I've updated my answer to accommodate what's mentioned in your comment to my answer.